# Calling onclick with local variable

Tags: javascript, google-closure

First, apologies for asking something that must be answered here somewhere (I've been looking!)

I want to do this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ...
  // Add an anchor to the dom
  ...
  a.onclick = goog.bind(this.doSomething, this);
  ...
}

namespace.Clazz.prototype.doSomething = function(event, index) {
  console.log('index: ' + index);
}
```

I want 5 anchors the each pass a different value for `i` to `doSomething` when clicked (along with the click event). I also want to keep the context of `this` in `doSomething` (hence the bind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reverse the order that the arguments are received, you should be able to do this...

```
a.onclick = goog.bind(this.doSomething, this, i);
```

---

So your `doSomething` should look like this...

```
namespace.Clazz.prototype.doSomething = function(index, event) {
  console.log('index: ' + index);
};
```

---

At least that's how it looks from [the Google Closure Library source](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js#973).

Answer (score 1):

```
a.onclick = (function(i) { return function() {goog.bind.....}; })(i);
```

That creates a new closure in which the value of i is fixed.

Comment: If I do: a.onclick = (function(i) { goog.bind(this.doSomething, this); })(i); a.onclick is ending up null...

Comment: There. The function(i) should return a function that becomes the onclick handler.

Comment: Hmm, still having a little trouble. Since 'am not i am' has a solution that works with me, I'm going with that. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work better for you:

```
a.onclick = function() {
    doSomething(this, i)
}
```

Comment: The value of `i` will change, though, as the loop continues.