# Onclick global function with local parameter

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, object

Follow-up after [a question about ordering XHR functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374246/error-with-setrequestheader-in-get-request)
It's a recursive situation where sendRequest() is creating a field with an onclick link to itself. This onclick link stores the variable word, that should be fed to sendRequest upon call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function inputReq(){
    sendRequest(wordform.word.value)
}
function sendRequest(str){
    //we start by removing the now superfluous rows
    table=document.getElementById('table')
    while(table.rows.length>2){
        table.deleteRow(2);
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log('sending request');
    request.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api.html?query='+str, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            json=request.responseText;
            console.log(json);
            //json.forEach(function(obj) { 
            //});
            for (word in json){
                var row=table.insertRow();
                var scoreC=row.insertCell();
                var wordC=row.insertCell();
                scoreC.innerHTML=json[word];
                wordC.innerHTML=word;
                wordC.onclick=(function(i)  {sendRequest(i);})(word);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Silence on the line");
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Query Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Query Page</h1>

<table id='table' style="width:100%">
<tr><form name='wordform'>
    <th>Concept: <input type="text" name="word"></th>
    <th><input type="button" onclick="inputReq()" value='Find Associations'></th>
</form></tr>
</body>
</html>
```

The XHR response looks like this:

```
{"milk": 1, "cheese": 3, "bread": 2}
```

I have been following [this schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919743/calling-onclick-with-local-variable) but this line is calling the function instead of adding the onclick link:

```
wordC.onclick=(function(i)  {sendRequest(i);})(word);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) it's called instantly. Place another function around it.

```
wordC.onclick = () => (function(i) { sendRequest(i); })(word);
```

(The above doesn't look like it's got the surrounding function, but it does - it's an ES6 arrow function).

Comment: After some corrections in the remaining code, onclick functions are generated